How to load a new model in LM Studio 0.3.5
I have installed LM Studio 0.3.5 on my new Mac Mini M4, I have loaded a model (Llama-3.1-8B) and I can chat. Everything is fine.
But now I would like to try other models (Mistral, etc.) and when I eject the Llama model, the only option I have is to re-load it.
I can't figure out how to display a list of all available models or to paste the link of a model on Huggingface.
Thank you in advance for your help.
